# Refinerycms: Can`t call controller from view pf different engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, refinerycms

I have two engines in refinerycms: product and order. I`m trying to call "create" method of orders while being on the product show page, but can`t get the right syntax.

The html is:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: 'orders', action: 'create'}, method: 'post') do %>
<%= submit_tag('Submit') %>
<% end %>
```

And the error is :

No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"refinery/products/orders", :id=>"category1", :locale=>:en}

The route I`m looking for is(from rake routes log):
orders_orders POST   /orders(.:format) refinery/orders/orders#create

I`ve tried different variants, like:

```
<%= form_tag(url_for({controller: 'orders', action: 'create'}), method: 'post') do %>
<%= submit_tag('Submit') %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag({controller: 'refinery/orders/', action: 'create'}, method: 'post') do %>
<%= submit_tag('Submit') %>
<% end %>
```

And some other. But had no luck.

How can I call 'create' method of orders from products/show page and transfer there correct params?

Comment: Have you tried this variant? <%= form_tag({controller: '/orders', action: 'create'}, method: 'post') do %>

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have used a kind of workaround to accomplish my goal. Do not know if this is a ruby-way, but still:
1. I have  created a new action in my products controller.

> def ordering
>        #Call any method you like.
>      end

2. I have added this in routes:

   post 'shop/products/ordering' => 'refinery/products/products#ordering'

Still this is not a good solution, because there is no way to call actually another controller`s method without directly creating an instance of this controller or marking the method as a class method, not instance.

In any case, I`d be very grateful  if someone could explain in details or show any documentation on how to do such things directly.

UDP: I`ve found a good way in search engine for this cms.

```
<%= form_tag refinery.search_root_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= label_tag 'query', t('.search_label') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, {}, {type: "search", placeholder: t(".search_site_for"), value: (params[:query] if params[:query])} %>
  <%= submit_tag t(".go") %>
<% end %>
```